# KeyboardInterrupt not working as I've thought it would, gotta know why and how to fix

Tags: python, loops, exception, keyboardinterrupt

I've built a chronometer using python, quite simple at first, and then I added a resume pause/resume command. So in the first passage, keyboardInterrupt works just fine, but when I restart the process, it restarts, go to the loop, but when I interrupt the execution, it just finisih the program without continuing to past statement and foward. I want to understand why this is happening, please
Code below:
I changed a little bit after an answer here, but it didnt work too. So i'm passing the modified code below my initial code.

'''python

```
def start_chronometer(passed: float = 0):

    import time
    beginning = time.time()
    n = 0
    try:
        while True:
            n += 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        past = (time.time() - beginning) + passed
        possibilities = ['Y', 'N']
        while (choice := input('Wish to resume counting ? y - Yes / n - No: ').title()) not in possibilities:
            print('Valor precisa ser "s" ou "n"')
        if choice == possibilities[0]:
            start_chronometer(passed=past)
        else:
            if 60 <= past < 3600:
                print(f'The time passed since the beginning of the counting was: {past / 60} minutes')
            elif 3600 <= past:
                print(f'The time passed since the beginning of the counting was: {past / 3600} hours')
            else:
                print(f'The time passed since the beginning of the counting was: {past} seconds')


start_chronometer()


def start_chronometer(passed: float = 0):
    while True:
        aux = passed
        import time
        beginning = time.time()
        n = 0
        try:
            while True:
                n += 1
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            past = (time.time() - beginning) + aux
            possibilities = ['Y', 'N']
            while (choice := input('Wish to resume counting ? y - Yes / n - No: ').title()) not in possibilities:
                print('Valor precisa ser "s" ou "n"')
            if choice == possibilities[0]:
                passed = past
                pass
            else:
                break
    if 60 <= past < 3600:
        print(f'The time passed since the beginning of the counting was: {past / 60} minutes')
    elif 3600 <= past:
        print(f'The time passed since the beginning of the counting was: {past / 3600} hours')
    else:
        print(f'The time passed since the beginning of the counting was: {past} seconds')
```

start_chronometer()

'''

Comment: can't reproduce the issue, please be more specific

Comment: _when I restart the process_ Do you mean you actually run the program again? Or do you mean you answer "y" to the question prompt?

Comment: That's it, I answer Y, and then it calls the function again, ok? So it "starts over" and run normally until de while loop, when I cause de second keyboardinterruption, the program just stop

Comment: When I cause the second keyboardInterruption it should ask me again if I want to resume counting, but it does not, just stops

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `except` handling block is outside of the `while True:` loop.

When you press ctrl-C the first time and choose to continue, `start_chronometer` runs recursively a second time.  But when the recursive function exits, the *original* execution keeps going and reaches the end of the function, because it is no longer in a loop.

Rearrange your code to put the `while True` loop around everything:

```
while True:
    try:
        n += 1
    except:
        ...
```

Also you'll need to add a `break` statement when the user chooses to stop, so that the loop will terminate.

Comment: I understand your solution, i see that it is also a possibility, but it still doesn't work... Same problem. The program just stops, at the second interruption

Comment: I don't see how that's possible.  Can you update the question with your new code?